# Possible bug in std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, unordered-map

I was trying to find the culprit behind a segfault. My debugger told be that there was no data for variable that the error was at. Every 10 seconds, there is a little script in my C++ code that runs. It does "garbage collection" and deletes some "sessions" that are probably dead.
To perform this efficiently, I use a timestamp -- when was the data last accessed. If the data is more than 10 seconds old, it is dead. There is a keepalive command that triggers every 4 seconds on the client.

To perform this GC, I loop through an std::unordered_map and substract the current time since epoch from the time stored as the value in that pair. If the time is too large, I add it to an std::vector that holds the keys to be deleted (yeah, I know it can be optimized to skip this step).

The problem that I was facing is that it loops right the first time. However, thereafter, I get a segfault, which points to the iterator value to be greater than size of the map.
Just switching back over to a standard std::map fixed the entire problem!

I shall attach the function that does all of this. All of the code is available at http://github.com/yash101/DrawingPad

Now, the code [{sourcedir}/source/Session.cxx]:

```
void SessionHost::cron()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
        if(DEBUG)
        {
            std::cout << "Cron has started!" << std::endl;
        }

        while(!locky_thingy.try_lock_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(MUTEX_TIMEOUT)))
        {}

        int timethrough = 0;
        std::vector<std::string> del;
        for(std::map<std::string, long>::iterator ite = timestamp.begin(); ite != timestamp.end(); ++ite)
        {
            timethrough++;
            std::cout << "Time through: " << timethrough << std::endl;
            std::string curkey = ite->first;
            long curval = ite->second;
            std::cout << "Key: " << curkey << std::endl;
            if(DEBUG)
            {
                std::cout << "Checking " << curkey << " with old ts of " << curval << std::endl;
            }

            u_int64_t curtm = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds> (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
            if(DEBUG)
            {
                std::cout << "Current time: " << curtm << std::endl;
            }
            if(curtm - curval > SESSION_TIMEOUT)
            {
                if(DEBUG)
                {
                    std::cout << "Deleted session handle: [" << curkey << "]" << std::endl;
                }
                del.push_back(curkey);
            }
            else
            {
                if(DEBUG)
                {
                    std::cout << "Kept back session handle: [" << curkey << "]" << std::endl;
                }
            }

            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < del.size(); i++)
            {
                timestamp.erase(del[i]);
                data.erase(del[i]);
                std::cout << "Erasing: " << del[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }

        locky_thingy.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: std::map<std::string, long> timestamp <== in {sourcedir}/include/Session.hxx

Comment: I see no use of `unordered_map` in this code

Comment: Are you doing anything in parallel? Make sure you have no data races when updating the map, as this invalidates the iterators, since you share the data. Otherwise, a simple loop over a `std::unordered_map` using `std::begin` and `std::end` should always work.

Comment: @vsoftco it's all locked with the aptly named `locky_thing` - I'm assuming everything shares that mutex?

Comment: locky_thingy is a timed_mutex. Everything is fully threaded

Comment: @Barry I think you got it right, haven't seen the erase line in OP's code.

Comment: I am trying to serialize all operations on all maps. That is what the mutex is for

Answer (score 7):

You have:

```
for(std::map<std::string, long>::iterator ite = timestamp.begin(); 
                                    ite != timestamp.end(); ++ite)
{
    // ...
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < del.size(); i++)
    {
        timestamp.erase(del[i]);   // <--
        // ...
    }
}
```

In an `unordered_map`, erasing can invalidate iterators. So you can't erase while you're traversing - try to come up with a different algorithm. (I'm assuming some version of your question involves `timestamp` being an `unordered_map` - although there's no reference to this type in your code).

Comment: he is using key to delete so that should be OK?

Comment: @Surt Not if `ite` is currently an iterator to the removed key. "References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other iterators and references are not invalidated."

Comment: I switched to the vector because I first load everything to be deleted. I then delete them from the map after the iterator has finished

Comment: @yash101 You need to move the `erase()` loop outside of the iterating-over-map loop. It's still inside.

Comment: Thank you, as you revealed me a future bug!

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is here

```
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < del.size(); i++)
        {
            timestamp.erase(del[i]);
            data.erase(del[i]); 
            std::cout << "Erasing: " << del[i] << std::endl;
        }
 } // <---------------- this is the end of the iterator loop
```

It should be moved up before the for loop so it doesn't invalidate.

```
 } // <---------------- this is the end of the iterator loop

 for(unsigned int i = 0; i < del.size(); i++)
      {
      timestamp.erase(del[i]);
      data.erase(del[i]); 
      std::cout << "Erasing: " << del[i] << std::endl;
 }
```

The data.erase might also have a fault if it is a vector.

If you have a vector you need to erase for you should mark the records and use

```
 data.erase(std::remove_if(data.begin(), data.(end), CheckMark));
```

remove_if moves all valid data to the start of data, erase then erases from after the last valid.

Comment: Hm. THat was supposed to be outside. however, the same error was occurring before I used the vector. I fixed the error using std::map instead of std::unordered_map

Comment: erase behaves different depended on the container it is called upon, bad design?

Comment: I guess. It's wierd how it was working after I changed to the regular map even though I was deleting while iterating!

Comment: @Surt, erase often invalidates iterators, it happens also for vectors, iterators beyond the erased positions are invalidated

Comment: @yash101, as long as you use the keys instead of iterators to erase you should not have problems with iterators.

Comment: I did std::string blah = ite->first;
timestamp.erase(blah);

Comment: If ite is an iterator to timestamp it could fail like vsoftco says, if the ite does not point to timestamp it should be OK as no iterator gets invalidated. You take `std::string curkey = ite->first;` and `del.push_back(curkey);` so the key gets decoupled from the ite and after the `for` is moved out of the `while` it should work.